# Make button execute css code and save on refresh

Tags: html, css, button

Im lost. I tryed everything but cant get it working.

What I am trying to do is have 2 buttons: one makes picture full-colored, second- black and white.

I know I can use `-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);` to make image black and white but I cant find way to activate this code thru html button. I also want color to be saved on refresh using `localStorage.getItem("somehting")`

I have working "model" with changing original picture with other one (it was my try to make one picture balck and white and other full color but i dont have tools to make it) so if you want I can upload it. Thanks

edit: jsfiddle.net/6hpqoypz This is what I use to change pictures between each other

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6hpqoypz/ This is what I use to change pictures between each other

Comment: Create a **working** fiddle with working image links, so we can try to help.Please remove non-english language text.

Comment: I just pasted because of code. Pictures and lanulage wont do anythig. I can do it only for you when i get back home.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working myself. For thoes who find this post by search I used this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<img id="Ispanija1" src='Ispanija1(n).gif'>
<button onclick="Ispanija1_t()"> Turiu.</button>
<button onclick="Ispanija1_n()"> Neturiu.</button>
<style id="Ispanija1style"></style>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', Ispanija1load1, false)
function Ispanija1_t() {document.getElementById("Ispanija1style").innerHTML="#Ispanija1"; localStorage.setItem('Ispanija1', "#Ispanija1");}
function Ispanija1_n() {document.getElementById("Ispanija1style").innerHTML="#Ispanija1 {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);}"; localStorage.setItem('Ispanija1', "#Ispanija1 {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);}");}   
var Ispanija1 = localStorage.getItem("Ispanija1")
function Ispanija1load1() {document.getElementById("Ispanija1style").innerHTML = Ispanija1}

</script>
</body>

</html>
```